# How can I edit a TreeModelFilters child model?

Tags: ruby, gtk2

I am currently trying to filter a `TreeView` based on the input of a text box, while still allowing the cells of the `TreeView` to be editable by the user.

The problem I'm running into is not being able to translate an edit on the `TreeView` while it's using the `TreeModelFilter` into an edit on the child model, which is a `ListStore`.

The signal_connect for the cell (`CellRendererText`) editing looks like this:

```
renderer.signal_connect('edited') do |w, s1, s2|
    cell_edited(s1, s2, treeview, $status)
end

def cell_edited(path, str, trvu, cell)
  if str != ""
    iter = @store.get_iter(path)
    iter[cell] = str
  end
end
```

Which I will admit to being something I found doing a search for editing TreeViews in Gtk2, as I am a GTK2 and GUI newbie in general.

How do I go about translating the path in the `TreeViewFilter` to the path in the child model (the `ListStore`)?

Or put more simply: when a user edits a cell in the table while it's filtered, how do I update the correct non-filtered entry in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You could write your code like below.  Its more concise, and it checks to make sure that the path is valid:

```
renderer.signal_connect('edited') do  |ren, path, text|
  next unless iter = @store.get_iter(path)
  iter[$status] = text if text != ""
end
```

You're doing everything correctly for a normal treeview, but when you make a Gtk::TreeModelFilter, you need to convert from the filtered iter to the child's iter using:

Gtk::TreeModelFilter#convert_iter_to_child_iter(filter_iter)

http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/ja/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3A%3ATreeModelFilter

So your code should read:

```
renderer.signal_connect('edited') do  |ren, path, text|
  next unless iter = @store.get_iter(path)
  child_iter = @child_store.convert_iter_to_child(iter) 
  child_iter[$status] = text if text != ""
end
```

You should have a look at visualruby.net.  I'll be releasing a new version that has a great listview/treeview where you have a much easier (and more rubyish) api.  The Gtk stuff gets very complicated.

Comment: Thanks for this!  I seemed to have to make a couple of alterations, but this worked perfectly after.  The changes I made were the next unless iter = needing to be my filter (@filter), rather than the store, and the .convert_iter_to_child_ITER (caps for emphasis) also needing to be used on the filter and not the store.  Thanks hugely for your help, and I will be checking out visualruby.net, as any way of making Gtk easier / more intuitive would be great!

Comment: Thanks.  I will be uploading the new version today that has the new listview and treeview stuff in it.  Let me know how it goes.  --E